# Why is my HttpPost ActionResult not getting reached?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, http-post

I'm working with two Views that are almost identical; their submit button click handling code *is* identical.

They both have, in their Controllers (which happen to live in the same file with each other), their own [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] methods. I have a breakpoint on the first line of each Http method:

```
public ActionResult TLISReport()
{
    var model = new TLISReportModel(); // <-- breakpoint on this line
    . . .

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TLISReport(TLISReportModel model)
{
    SetUpTLISCombos(); // <-- breakpoint on this line
    . . .

public ActionResult ReceiptCriteria()
{
    var model = new TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel(); // <-- breakpoint on this line
    . . .

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceiptCriteria(TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel model) 
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // <-- breakpoint on this line
    . . .
```

In the case of "ReceiptCriteria", the default HttpGet method is being reached both when I first navigate to the page and when I select the "Submit" button, but the HttpPost is also reached after that; in the case of "TLISReport", though, only the undecorated (HttpGet) ActionResult is reached - the breakpoint for HttpPost for TLISReport is never reached.

Why would that be?

### UPDATE

To answer WannaCSharp's question, both the HTML:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit_button" class="bottomButtonEnabled">View Report</button>
```

...and the click event handler are exactly the same for both Views:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function () {
 . . .
```

### UPDATE 2

Running the app/site, those four methods are reached in this order:

0) **[HttpGet] public ActionResult ReceiptCriteria()**

After I mash the submit button on the Receipt Report Criteria page:

1) **[HttpGet] public ActionResult ReceiptCriteria()**
- followed by:

2) **[HttpPost] public ActionResult ReceiptCriteria(TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel model)**

The same exact thing (now, since I explicitly added the "[HttpGet]" decoration, takes place with TLISReport:
Selecting that report invokes

3) **[HttpGet] public ActionResult TLISReport()**

After I mash the submit button on the TLIS Report Criteria page:

4) **[HttpGet] public ActionResult TLISReport()**

- followed by:

5) **[HttpPost] public ActionResult TLISReport(TLISReportModel model)**

So why is a post not just posting but also getting? That seems like a waste of energy for the gerbils powering the machine.

### UPDATE 3

In response to Dismissile's request, here is the Submit code in its entirety, no-holds-barred:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function () {
    var begD = $('#BeginDateTime').val();
    var endD = $('#EndDateTime').val();
    if (begD > endD) {
        alert('Begin date must be before End date');
        $('#BeginDateTime').focus();
        return false;
    }

    $("#NumberOfResults").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#NumberOfResults").html("Please wait...");

    EnableButton("submit_button", false);

    // If all are selected, don't enumerate them; just set it at "All" (change of case shows that the logic did execute)
    var deptsList = $('#depts').checkedBoxes();
    if (deptsList.length < deptsArray.length) {
        $('#deptHeader span').html(deptsList.join(", "));
    }
    else if (deptsList.length == deptsArray.length) {
        $('#deptHeader span').html("All");
    }
    // " "
    var sitesList = $('#sites').checkedBoxes();
    $('#sitesHeader span').html(sitesList.join(", "));
    if (sitesList.length < sitesArray.length) {
        $('#sitesHeader span').html(sitesList.join(", "));
    }
    else if (sitesList.length == sitesArray.length) {
        $('#sitesHeader span').html("All");
    }

    $('#hiddenDepts').val(deptsList);
    $('#hiddenSites').val(sitesList);

    var resultsText = jQuery.trim($("#spanNumberOfResults").text());
    if (resultsText != "") {
        $("#NumberOfResults").css("visibility", "visible");

        if (resultsText == "0") {
            $("#NumberOfResults").css("color", "red");
        } else {
            var href = '/@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThisApp"]/TLDCriteria/LoadReport';
            var report_parms = {
                GUID: "@Model.GUID",
                SerialNumber: "@Model.SerialNumber",
                ReportName: "@Model.ReportName"
            };
            window.open(href, "report_window", "resizable=1, width=850, left=" + (screen.width / 2 - 425));
        }
    }
    console.log('made it to the end of submit button click');
}); // end of submit button click
```

### UPDATE 4

More info in response to dismissile's missive:

0) From TLDCriteriaController.cs:

```
public ActionResult LoadReport()
{
    return View();
}
```

1) LoadReport.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Preview</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
                width: 100%;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #silverlightControlHost {
                height: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
            <div id="silverlightControlHost">
                <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
                        width="100%" height="100%">
                    <param name="source" value="@Url.Content("~/ClientBin/TLDReporter-SL.xap")" />
                    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                    <param name="background" value="white" />
                    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60310.0" />
                    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60310.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                             style="border-style: none" />
                    </a>
                </object>
                <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="border: 0; height: 0; visibility: hidden; width: 0;"></iframe>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/handle_silverlight_error-1.0.0.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js")" type="text/javascript" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function get_user_name() {
                return "@User.Identity.Name";
            }

            function get_xml_data() {
                return window.opener.xml_data;
            }

            function get_receipt_parms() {
                return window.opener.receipt_parms;
            }

            function get_report_parms() {
                return window.opener.report_parms;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: Looks like an issue with your model binder for TLDSalesReceiptCriteriaModel ...

Comment: Are you sure both overloads of `ReceiptCriteria` are being reached when you submit your form? If you're doing a `POST` to the server, only the post action should be reached...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, some of the model/controller code was unmatched, but why would that cause the HttpPost method not to be called?

Comment: @DaveZych: Yes, that's what I would expect, too, but I have breakpoints in both the Get and the Post, and the Get is always reached, and the Post is sometimes reached after it.

Comment: @ClayShannon I think the . . . in your javascript is important to see and might give us more details on why it's doing both. Are you trying to make an async request using jQuery? It almost seems like it's doing both an async request and a regular form submission (might be missing an event.preventDefault())

Comment: Okay, I'll add the entire submit code in Update 3.

Comment: This is a bit late but what does your LoadReport action do?

Comment: @Dismissile: czech Update 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `[HttpGet]` on the action results that do not have [HttpPost]. It looks like it can't figure out which one to use.

Comment: +1 It may solve the issue. At very least it will prevent matching to default action and force some better error why routing can't match POST one with model.

Comment: See Update 2 for some more info regarding this.